# need feedback on an analysis proof

Tags: real-analysis

**Question:**

Let $(s_n)$ be a convergent sequence, and suppose that $\lim_{n\to\infty} s_n \gt a$. Prove there exists a number $N$ such that $n\gt N$ implies $s_n \gt a$.

**My attempt:**

Since $s_n$ is convergent then $\lim_{n\to\infty} s_n = s$ for some $s \in \Bbb{R}$. Then for $\epsilon \gt 0$ There exists $N \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $n \gt N \implies |s_n -s| \lt \epsilon$. It is given that $s \gt a$. Therefore $s-a \gt 0$. Take $\epsilon = (s-a)$. Then $n \gt N \implies |s_n -s| \lt (s-a) \implies$ for all $n \gt N$, $s_n \gt a$. Therefore $N$ exists.

I think this is ok but not 100% sure. Are there any holes in my logic?

Comment: I think your proof look okay.

Comment: Why $|s_n - s| < s-a \implies s_n >a$ ??? That's not clear to me

Comment: It's fine, but @Luis is right that you should show the algebra justifying your last statement.

Comment: @Luis and Ted, ok thanks. I think it is clear when writing out the proof but to an onlooker I see your point. .

Answer (score 1):

Looks ok to me.

To further emphasize that $N$ depends on $\epsilon$, some books write $N(\epsilon)$, but that is optional.